# How to append text into a variable in a different python file?

Tags: python, list, variables, append

I'm trying to make a code that would take the information a user inputs and adds it permanently to a different file's variable:

main.py:

```
text = "hello world"
f = open("Testfile.py", "a+")
f.write(text)
```

Testfile.py:

```
w = ["bob", "joe", "emily"]Hello World
```

how can I make it so that "Hello World" would appear in w such as

`w = ["bob", "joe", "emily", "Hello World"]`

Edit:

what if w is a library such as
`w = {"bob": 0, "joe": 0, "emily" : 0}`
and I want to add `"Hello World" : 0` to it

Comment: I don't know what your end goal is with this but this is almost certainly not a good way to approach it. Programs that modify other programs can get messy quickly. Any bugs you have could destroy your code and require you to start over again.

Comment: Start point: `ast` module. `m = ast.parse(open('Testfile.py').read())`, do what you want then `ast.unparse(m)`. Use `ast.walk` (Try: `list(ast.walk(m))`)

Comment: about your edit (and original question): just use a `json` file (for the edit info, otherwise any of the answers given), you don't want to write to an actual python file that will be later used, there is no need for that and it can get buggy pretty easily

Comment: This is really not a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm trying to make a discord bot that would keep track of people's points that is why i need a dictionary to keep track of these points and to be "editable"

Comment: Yeah, this is still not a reasonable way of doing this. Use one of the many different data formats, e.g. JSON, yaml, or even pickle, to save your data to a file.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so what do I do if I make a JSON file? I've never used that before

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necessary to store the content of you array to a python file?
You could store it into a yaml file for instance instead, and you a yaml library to write and read the content to/from that file.

```
import yaml
import os

def load_yaml(filename):
  with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
    y = yaml.safe_load(fp)
    return y
def save_yaml(content, filename):
  if os.path.exists(filename):
    os.remove(filename)
  with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
    yaml.safe_dump(content, fp, default_flow_style=False)

w = ["bob", "joe", "emily"]
save_yaml(w, "data.yaml")
w.append("hello world")
save_yaml(w, "data.yaml")
content = load_yaml("data.yaml")
print(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend not modifying a python file programmatically. You will likely be able to accomplish the same task by storing your list in a text file and having any program read the text file and build the list. There are other file formats you could use for more complicated tasks, but for simply putting strings in a list this code is sufficient. Some kind of full-on database would be best for a real-world application.

test.txt:

```
bob
joe
emily
```

main.py:

```py
def read_file():
    f = open('test.txt', 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [line.strip() for line in lines] #removes the '\n' character at the end of each line
    print(lines)
    f.close()

def append_file(item):
    f = open('test.txt', 'a')
    f.write(item)
    f.write('\n')
    f.close()

read_file()
append_file("Hello World")
append_file("test")
read_file()
```

Also as a bonus, you can use `with` to manage file objects more concisely.

```py
def read_file():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        lines = [line.strip() for line in lines] #removes the '\n' character at the end of each line
        print(lines)


def append_file(item):
    with open('test.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(item)
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: also instead of `lines = f.readlines()` AND `lines = [lines.strip() for line in line]` do `lines = [line.strip() for line in f]`, it will be one line less of code and  possibly faster and also there is no need for two lines of `f.write`, you can just concatenate those strings